# Why my validation accuracy is starting in 98%? is for overfitting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm training a neural network for voice activity detection and my validation accuracy starts at 98% and stays in this percentage meanwhile training accuracy start lower and reaches validation accuracy at the final of training. Is this overfitting or the model is fine?

Here is the code:

```
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='elu'), input_shape=(None, 32, 32, 1)))
    model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))))
    model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu')))
    model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))))
    model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu')))
    model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))))
    model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Flatten()))
    model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(64, activation='elu')))
    model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(output_layer_width, activation='softmax')))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
 return model
```

Is from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.03529

The epochs are 80 and the batch size is 64.

Here are the learning curves:

[image: Accuracy]

[image: Loss error]

Edit: I'm adding more context. The dataset is made from signals from 1 minute with 30 s of noise and 30 s of noisy speech. Is select 20% of the data randomly for validation?

Comment: Is your data splitted correctly? make sure no samples from the training and validation set are getting mixed with samples from the test set.

Comment: Maybe your model is already trained with your validation test

Comment: @pazitos10 the test set is the 20% of the total dataset and was selected randomly and reserved. The validation set is the 20% of the of the remaining dataset and also was selected radomly.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos how so? can you explain?

Comment: I mean, maybe you overwrite your sets and your model is training with whole your data.

Comment: Is possible that your validation set is suffering with class imbalancing? It is a common problem with binary classification. Print count of reach class samples to find out. Perform stratified sampling, over/under sampling to balance classes.

Comment: Please note that you have people here guessing the reason, that is not how Stack Overflow works. Also note that this is not a programming problem, making the question off-topic.